# approach to create a reactjs package to include exported sass variables

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass

I already have a great project that exports and is easily imported into other projects, and is in a private npm registry.

However, I have sass variables in this project that I would like to use in the consuming project. How do I go about exporting my scss file that has all of the variables so that I can import it into my scss files.

Ideally, something like

`@import 'package/scss/colors'`

I am currently using rollup and its plugin rollup-plugin-postcss, but am not married to it if there's a better way